# IOCP recv AND send

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, asyncsocket, iocp

All the examples I have found so far either only read OR write or were 10000 line beasts where I didn't even know where to start to understand how they work.

To test my code I pointed a browser at my server and sent a simple http request. The results are confusing.

For example at one point GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns and WSARecv says it read the number of bytes of the http response I sent although this response should (and does) end up at the client and the recvbuffer isn't even filled with those bytes.

Also I don't understand when to free my buffers once the other browser closes the connection since GetQueuedCompletionStatus keeps returning a few times after my call to closesocket.

Further I don't know when there is data to read or data to write once GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns. I could just try both and see which fails but that seems rude.

To reveal any misconceptions I might have about IOCP I wrote some pseudo code to convey what I think my code does:

```
main {
    create server socket
    create io completion port
    while true {
        accept client socket
        create completion port for client socket
        create recv buffer and send buffer for client
        call WSARecv once with 0 bytes for whatever reason
    }
}

worker thread {
    while true {
        wait until GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns
        do something if that failed, not quite sure what (free buffers?)
        if no bytes were transferred, close socket
        try to recv data
        try to send data
    }
}
```

Actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

typedef struct {
    WSAOVERLAPPED overlapped;
    SOCKET socket;
    WSABUF sendbuf;
    WSABUF recvbuf;
    char sendbuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char recvbuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
} client;

DWORD WINAPI worker_thread(HANDLE iocp){
    DWORD flags = 0, n = 0;
    ULONG unused;
    client *c;

    while (1){
        int ret = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, &n, &unused, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&c, INFINITE);
        printf("%3d triggered\n", c->socket);

        if (ret == FALSE){
            printf("%3d GetQueuedCompletionStatus error %i\n", c->socket, WSAGetLastError());
            continue;
        }

        if (c->socket == INVALID_SOCKET){
            printf("error: socket already closed\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (n == 0) {
            printf("%3d disconnected\n", c->socket);
            closesocket(c->socket);
            c->socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }

        /* how do I know if there is data to read or data to write? */

        WSARecv(c->socket, &(c->recvbuf), 1, &n, &flags, &(c->overlapped), NULL);
        printf("%3d WSARecv %ld bytes\n", c->socket, n);

        WSASend(c->socket, &(c->sendbuf), 1, &n, flags, &(c->overlapped), NULL);
        printf("%3d WSASend %ld bytes\n", c->socket, n);

        /* TODO handle partial sends */
        c->sendbuf.len = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

SOCKET make_server(int port){
    int yes = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    SOCKET sock;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    sock = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);

    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)yes, sizeof(yes));

    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);

    return sock;
}

int main(){
    const char *text =
        "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
        "Content-Length: 13\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        "Connection: Close\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "Hello, World!";

    SOCKET server_socket = make_server(8080);

    HANDLE iocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, worker_thread, iocp, 0, NULL);

    while (1){
        DWORD flags = 0, n = 0;
        client *c;
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        int addrlen = sizeof(addr);

        SOCKET client_socket = WSAAccept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen, NULL, 0);

        printf("%3d connected\n", client_socket);

        CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)client_socket, iocp, 0, 0);

        c = (client*)calloc(1, sizeof(*c));

        c->socket = client_socket;
        c->sendbuf.len = strlen(text);
        c->recvbuf.len = BUFFER_SIZE;
        c->sendbuf.buf = c->sendbuffer;
        c->recvbuf.buf = c->recvbuffer;
        strcpy(c->sendbuf.buf, text);

        /* for some reason I have to receive 0 bytes once */
        WSARecv(c->socket, &(c->recvbuf), 1, &n, &flags, &(c->overlapped), NULL);
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
/* Browser makes two tcp connections on socket 124 and 128. */
124 connected
128 connected

/* GetQueuedCompletionStatus returned for socket 124. */
124 triggered

/* We received the browser's http request. */
124 WSARecv 375 bytes

/* Send http response to browser. */
124 WSASend 96 bytes

/* GetQueuedCompletionStatus returned again. */
124 triggered

/* This is wrong, we should not receive our response to the browser. */
/* Also we didn't even receive data here. */
/* recvbuffer still contains the http request. */
124 WSARecv 96 bytes

/* this is ok */
124 WSASend 0 bytes
124 triggered
124 disconnected

/* Why does GetQueuedCompletionStatus still return? the socket is closed! */
/* Also how can I tell when I can safely free the buffers */
/* if GetQueuedCompletionStatus keeps returning? */
 -1 triggered
 -1 GetQueuedCompletionStatus error 1236
 -1 triggered
 -1 GetQueuedCompletionStatus error 1236

/* same again for second http request */
128 triggered
128 WSARecv 375 bytes
128 WSASend 96 bytes
128 triggered
128 WSARecv 96 bytes
128 WSASend 0 bytes
128 triggered
128 disconnected
 -1 triggered
 -1 GetQueuedCompletionStatus error 1236
 -1 triggered
 -1 GetQueuedCompletionStatus error 1236
128 connected
128 triggered
128 WSARecv 375 bytes
128 WSASend 96 bytes
128 triggered
128 WSARecv 96 bytes
128 WSASend 0 bytes
128 triggered
128 disconnected
 -1 triggered
 -1 GetQueuedCompletionStatus error 1236
 -1 triggered
 -1 GetQueuedCompletionStatus error 1236
128 connected
128 triggered
128 WSARecv 289 bytes
128 WSASend 96 bytes
128 triggered
128 WSARecv 96 bytes
128 WSASend 0 bytes
128 triggered
128 disconnected
 -1 triggered
 -1 GetQueuedCompletionStatus error 1236
 -1 triggered
 -1 GetQueuedCompletionStatus error 1236
```

Comment: I have some example IOCP code that you could look at if you want, see here: http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html

Comment: @Optimus1, I'm sorry if you didn't find the link useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pseudo code workflow should look more like this instead:

```
main {
    create server socket
    create io completion port
    create worker thread
    while not done {
        accept client socket
        associate client socket with completion port
        create recv, send, and work buffers for client
        call WSARecv with >0 bytes to start filling recv buffer
        if failed {
            close client socket and free associated buffers
        }
    }
    terminate worker thread
    close client sockets
    close server socket
}

worker thread {
    while not terminated {
        call GetQueuedCompletionStatus
        if failed {
            if failed because of IO error {
                close socket and free associated buffers
            }
            else if not timeout {
                handle error as needed
            }
        }
        else if no bytes were transferred {
            close socket and free associated buffers
        }
        else if IO was WSARecv {
            move data from recv buffer to end of work buffer
            while work buffer has a complete message {
                remove message from front of work buffer, process as needed
                if output to send {
                    if send buffer not empty {
                        append output to end of send buffer, will send later
                    }
                    else {
                        move output to send buffer
                        call WSASend
                        if failed {
                            close socket and free associated buffers
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            call WSARecv with >0 bytes to start filling recv buffer
            if failed {
                close socket and free associated buffers
            }
        }
        else if IO was WSASend {
            remove reported number of bytes from front of send buffer
            if send buffer not empty {
                call WSASend
                if failed {
                    close socket and free associated buffers
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will leave it as an exercise for you to translate that into your code.

Comment: IMHO, Your failure handling is too simplistic. A failed read, due to client close, does not require that you shutdown your send side, unless you want to... Also I assume that 'free associated buffers' relates only to the buffers used by the operation that failed...

Comment: It was a simple workflow for a simple example project. In a real-world complex project, error handling can be equally complex. For instance, if an inbound read fails and an outbound send is already in flight, you can stop reading and free the recv buffer immediately, but delay closing the socket and freeing the send buffer until the active send finishes/fails first.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted that noted as otherwise simplistic error handling in simple examples tends to end up as being the real thing in production code...

Answer (score 1):

I got the majority of my information from reverse engineering [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10330/A-simple-IOCP-Server-Client-Class).
I do have to warn you not to use this code though it is full of bugs and bad behaviors, it was made for a much earlier version of windows.

BUT the general principles are similar so it is a good exercise to see how much you can learn from it (but whatever you do don't use it without heavy modification).
The best code sections are in `IOCPDlg.cpp` and `IOCPDlg.h`.

The general Principle with IOCP and Reads is that there should always be 1 read request queued for each port. Of course unless you don't want to read from it.

With completed statuses in your worker thread you should do the following:

- Check to see if there is an error using the return code of `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` and `GetLastError()`:
- Process the error, but filter out timeouts (read timeouts aren't errors as such):

  `if (!ReturnValue && GetErrorValue != ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT ) {
      /-- i free up the socket and associated buffers here --/
      continue;
  }`
- Process IO. I use the following to differentiate IO (I'll add the code for it at the bottom):

  `/-- get the base address of the struct holding lpOverlapped --/
  pOverlapPlus = CONTAINING_RECORD(lpOverlapped, OVERLAPPEDPLUS, ol);`
- If the IO you just processed is of type `IORead` then queue another read.
- Sending should not be done in this thread, a different thread / function should be adding Send IO requests to the IOCP.
- Free the OVERLAPPEDPLUS class, you need to make a new one for each request so you need to free it after each request is dequeued.

---

Code for OVERLAPPEDPLUS, Can be found in [CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10330/A-simple-IOCP-Server-Client-Class).

```
enum IOType 
{
    IOInitialize,
    IORead,
    IOWrite,
    IOIdle
};

class OVERLAPPEDPLUS 
{
public:
    OVERLAPPED ol;
    IOType ioType;

    OVERLAPPEDPLUS(IOType _ioType)
    {
        ZeroMemory(this, sizeof(OVERLAPPEDPLUS));
        ioType = _ioType;
    }
};
```

Comment: I also learn about iocp from the code, you have mentioned. Could you say something more about " bugs and bad behaviors" in this code? Thx in advance.

Comment: The two major ones I remember are that `WAIT_TIMEOUT` should be `ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT`, The lack of a write semaphore, and writes that would trigger on 0 bytes remaining which can be fixed by testing to see if the buffer has 0 bytes remaining before queueing the final send request. Apart from those 3 major things there were some minor things (I can't remember) to do with MFC, which should be OK since any new projects should not use MFC anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a state variable for you to know if you are reading or writing (or possibly other io operation state...you initialize that state variable to read in your main routine (before you issue a wsarecv), and set that state variable to write whenever you are sending, that way in the worker thread you query that state variable to know if you are reading or sending

in your worker thread:

```
switch (state_var)
{
  case IO_READ:
    //process wsarecv
    //process data
    break;
  case IO_SEND:
    //process wsasend
    //send more data
    //if there are no more to send
    //state_var = IO_READ;
    //call wsarecv
    break;
  //process other io command you define
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* for some reason I have to receive 0 bytes once */
 WSARecv(c->socket, &(c->recvbuf), 1, &n, &flags, &(c->overlapped),NULL);
```

I had same doubt but it got cleared.

At first, Completion queue is empty and thread is unable to dequeue any completed process of any socket, because we have to do some operation with socket to enqueue it into Completion queue.

Then only thread will be able to dequeue it from completion queue in the `WORKER_THREAD()` function from `GETQUEUEDCOMPLETIONSTATUS()`.

Therefore we have to do some operation like `WSArecv()`.